# problems with making class variable public

Tags: c++

Why can't we make `class` variables `public`? Even if we are making it `private`, we are utilizing it as a `public` variable  so what's the point?

Also, what is the error in this code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class myClass{
public:
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

int main(){
    myClass myObj;
    myObj.setName = "D78iu98`";
    cout << pubObj.getName<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If you compile it the compiler would tell you the errors.

Answer (score 2):

The main argument is encapsulation, but **you're right**. Providing public getters and setters (effectively exposing the variable as a `public` one) breaks encapsulation and is only slightly better than having it `public` because it provides a single access point (i.e. you can break execution via a breakpoint inside the getter/setter).

For your questions - `setName` and `getName` are methods, use them as such.

Comment: Since debuggers generally can break on reading/writing to a variable, the debugging point might not be as important (it is, of course, still important if you want to break on any modification, rather than a particular one)

Comment: @SergeyA I'd love to hear about how you can break when reading a variable. Can you do it in visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, no idea on Visual Studio, but I am pretty sure it should be able to do so - simply because it is competiteve product. gdb/dbx (my stapple) can break on read, write or both on any variable - but it should be a specifc address. That is to say, you can break on a modification of a member of a particular object (instance of a class), but not on the modification of a member in any instance of a given class. Makes sense?

Comment: @SergeyA in VS those are data brakpoints, but to my knowledge you can only break on write.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific error: `myObj.setName = "name";` does not make sense. You need to *call* the function correctly: `myObj.setName("name");` is the correct calling syntax. (C++ does provide mechanisms that would make your particular syntax valid but these are beyond the scope of this answer.)

The idea behind making variables `private` is to *encapsulate* the data in the class. This can help prevent the object becoming internally inconsistent.

That said, providing a get and a set to and from a single member circumvents encapsulation. If that is what's needed in a particular instance, then consider making the member `public`.

I prefer to set as many of the member data as possible *on construction*, and provide `get` methods if necessary.

Moving on, consider changing your `get` method to return a *constant reference* to the data member: `const string& getName()`. This prevents the taking of a string copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
```

## include

using namespace std;

class myClass{
public:
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

int main(){
    myClass myObj;
    myObj.setName("D78iu98`");
    cout<